# Maven run unit tests without integration tests, and integration tests without unit tests

Tags: java, maven

I have structure:

```
 - test
   - java
       - com
          - A
             - service
                 - serviceB
                    - DefaultServiceBTest.java
                    - integration
                          - DefaultServiceBIntegrationTest.java
```

I want to run separately unit and integration tests. I am using maven surefire and failsafe plugins:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
        <printSummary>true</printSummary>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>integration/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Since `mvn test` defaultly runs `surefire:test` having this configuration for `maven-surefire` works, and using `mvn test` only runs unit tests - in my case all tests that are not in `integration` folder.

However for failsafe i have this configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.failsafe.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/integration/*.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Having this configuration for `maven-failsafe` and running `mvn verify -Pfailsafe` results in first running unit tests, and then integration tests. However i dont want the unit tests to be executed with this. What is wrong with the configuration?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

First you should not separate your unit tests from integration tests by using different directories. Use the existing naming conventions. Unit Test `*Test.java` and integration tests `*IT.java`...

Use the following [configuration in your POM File](https://github.com/khmarbaise/youtube-videos/tree/main/episode-2):

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.soebes.youtube.maven.episodes</groupId>
  <artifactId>example-episode-2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>Episode 2: Unit- and/or Integration Testing</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.1</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
      <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.10.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M8</version>
          <configuration>
            <skipTests>${skipUTs}</skipTests>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M8</version>
          <configuration>
            <skipTests>${skipITs}</skipTests>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

By using that you can run your unit tests via:

```
mvn test
```

You can run your unit- and your integration tests via:

```
mvn verify
```

If you like to run your integration tests only:

```
mvn verify -DskipUTs
```

For detail explanations you could check the following [YT video](https://youtu.be/IVwbrhYCLpc).